# Difference between WebExpressionVoter and AuthenticatedVoter in spring security

Tags: spring-security

What is the difference between WebExpressionVoter and AuthenticatedVoter in spring security? What I know is AuthenticatedVoter will search for strings IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED (cookie) and vote for yes in corresponding cases. But I am not sure of WebExpressionVoter even afetr reading available spring docs. Please any one explain me about WebExpressionVoter. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Web Security Expressions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.0.RC2/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access-web).

The `WebExpressionsVoter` is enabled by the `use-expressions="true"` setting on `http` element config. For example:

`<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin*" access="hasRole('admin')"/>
    ...
</http>`

The above example allows you to use [SpEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#expressions) expressions in the `intercept-url` element attribute `access`. The expression `hasRole('admin')` expression is evaluated against an expression root object, for example, a base class of `SecurityExpressionRoot` -> `WebSecurityExpressionRoot`